# TinyMCE disable stripping style tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there anyway to disable TinyMCE from stripping style tags without using fullpage plugin? I don't want full page. The editor is just for a part of a page. This editor is also used internally only so no need for stripping anything basically.

This is my test source:

```
<style>
p{
    color: red;
}
</style>
<p>test</p>
<script>
    console.log('test');
</script>
```

I have tried adding following to config:

```
valid_children : '+body[style]'
```

Result I get after clicking OK and going back to source mode is following:

```
<style><!--
p{
color: red;
}
--></style>
<p>test</p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
console.log('test');
// ]]></script>
```

These weird comment tags get added to the style tag.